# Get method is getting invoked twice in Safari

Tags: post, safari, get, sap-commerce-cloud

Whenever I'm trying to hit a page in my website, each page is invoking GET method 2 times in **Safari**. However it works fine in rest of browsers. Also, on posting a result, if a page returns error in page. Only POST is called but posting same data again calls POST and GET both. Any idea why is it happening? Am i missing something?

Site link:- [Click on the link](http://113.192.44.248/)

Comment: Can you post related codes here?

Comment: Hi, I used a simple java controller code to return the page needs to be opened.
Code snippet of controller is:-
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-delivery-address", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String addDeliveryAddress(@RequestParam(value = "address", required = false)
    final String addressNeeded, final Model model){

        if (!hasValidCart()) {
            LOG.info("Missing, empty or unsupported cart");
            return REDIRECT_URL_CART;
        }
        
//page content
        return ControllerConstants.Views.Pages.MultiStepCheckout.AddEditDeliveryAddressPage;
    }

Comment: You can check it through the link defined. It works fine in all browsers except safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is resolved.

I was using img with empty source tag  which caused Safari to invoke GET method twice.